# Subsetting Outliers from a data frame by using the results of a boxplot diagram

Tags: r, subset, rounding

I transformed my data into a boxplot (used geom_boxplot of ggplot), so that the outliers got visible. Afterwards I wanted to remove them from my data. That is why I used "ggplot_build" to get on all the informations of the plot and saved it with a new name.

```
Outlier_boxplot<-ggplot_build(boxplot)
```

Now it was possible to extract the column with the outliers. In the next step I used the function "subset" to select only the values of my data.frame, which are not equal to the extracted outliers.

```
Without_Outlier_dF<-subset(round(dF[1],digits=3),Test !=c(round(Outlier_boxplot$data[[1]]$outliers[[4]],digits=3))))
```

That worked out well for nearly all cases. The problem is, that sometimes values (even so they look the same) are not left out.

Extract of values data.frame:

```
-234,347 75,764 93,34   95,237  99,005  100,044 97,924  98,875  98,072  99,569  98,848  98,414  99,33   96,901  99,29   100,359 99,169  97,828  97,146  97,229  94,278  97,146  97,229  94,278
```

Outliers

```
-234.347   75.764   93.340   94.278
```

Results: Outliers removed except for the value 94,278

```
95,237  99,005  100,044 97,924  98,875  98,072  99,569  98,848  98,414  99,33   96,901  99,29   100,359 99,169  97,828  97,146  97,229  94,278
```

I already tried to round all values (as you can see) but it didn't help. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geom_boxplot` calls `boxplot.stats` to calculate the positions of the upper and lower whiskers. You can do it too:

```
> boxplot.stats(v)
$stats
[1]  93.340  96.069  97.876  99.087 100.359

$n
[1] 24

$conf
[1] 96.90265 98.84935

$out
[1] -234.347   75.764
```

(`v` is assumed to be your input data vector):

From the `boxplot.stats` documentation:

> stats  a vector of length 5, containing the extreme of the lower
>   whisker, the lower ‘hinge’, the median, the upper ‘hinge’ and the
>   extreme of the upper whisker.
>
> n  the number of non-NA observations in the sample.
>
> conf   the lower and upper extremes of the ‘notch’ (if(do.conf)). See
>   the details.
>
> out    the values of any data points which lie beyond the extremes of
>   the whiskers (if(do.out)).

I guess it contains all the data you might need for further analysis.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot. I used the extremes of the upper and lower whisker as limits for the subset command and then it removed all outliers.